# Jquery append vs appendTo

Tags: jquery, append

Can someone explain why I can append a string to a `<p>` tag but I cannot appendTo. This is my code

```
$('#append').click(function(){
  $('p:first').append('hello');
});

$('#appendTo').click(function(){
 $('hello').appendTo('p:first');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is because of how the string parameters are interpreted in both these cases.

When you say `$('hello')`, `'hello'` act as a selector where it searches for an element with tagname `hello` which is not present in the dom structure. But you can say `$('<span>Hello</span>').appendTo('p:first')` because here `<span>Hello</span>` is interpreted as creating a new `span` element

Where as [append()](https://api.jquery.com/append/) considers the passed string as html content and will append it to the called set of elements.